# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

[Table relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMh4E.png)> I am trying to insert the data in 3 different tables - **JV_SNAPSHOT, JV_GLOBAL_ID, JV_COMMIT**. It's corresponding Bean class are given below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JV_SNAPSHOT")
public class JVSnapshot {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jv_snapshot_pk_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="jv_snapshot_pk_seq", sequenceName = "JV_SNAPSHOT_PK_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "SNAPSHOT_PK")
    private long snapshotID;
    
    @Column(name="VERSION")
    private long version;
    
    @Column(name="GLOBAL_ID_FK")
    private long globalID;
    
    @Column(name="COMMIT_FK")
    private long commitID;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;
    
    @Column(name = "MANAGED_TYPE")
    private String managedType;
    
    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private String state;
    
    @Column(name = "CHANGED_PROPERTIES")
    private String changedProperties;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "jvSnapshot")
    //@JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private JVGlobalID jvGlobalID;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "jvSnapshot")
    //@JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private JVCommit jvCommit;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JV_GLOBAL_ID")
public class JVGlobalID {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jv_global_id_pk_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="jv_global_id_pk_seq", sequenceName = "JV_GLOBAL_ID_PK_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "GLOBAL_ID_PK")
    private long globalID;

    @Column(name = "LOCAL_ID")
    private String localID;
    
    @Column(name = "FRAGMENT")
    private String fragment;
    
    @Column(name = "TYPE_NAME")
    private String typeName;
    
    @Column(name="OWNER_ID_FK")
    private long ownerID;
    
    @OneToOne @MapsId
    private JVSnapshot jvSnapshot;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JV_COMMIT")
public class JVCommit {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jv_commit_pk_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="jv_commit_pk_seq", sequenceName = "JV_COMMIT_PK_SEQ")
    @Column(name= "COMMIT_PK" , insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;
    
    @Column(name = "COMMIT_DATE")
    private Date commitDate;
    
    @Column(name = "COMMIT_DATE_INSTANT")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private String commitDateInstant;
    
    @Column(name="COMMIT_ID")
    private long commitId;  
    
    @OneToOne @MapsId
    private JVSnapshot jvSnapshot;
```

> The Service class where entire business logic to calculate the values and inserting the data is given below:

```
JVSnapshot jvSnapshot = new JVSnapshot();
//inserting data into JV_GLOBAL_ID table
System.out.println("Inserting in JV_GLOBAL_ID table");
JVGlobalID jvGlobalId = new JVGlobalID();
jvGlobalId.setTypeName("com.dev.neo.models.Customer");
jvGlobalId.setLocalID("99999");
jvCommitGlobalIdRepository.save(jvGlobalId); //globalID generated (PK)
System.out.println("Data inserted in jvcommitGlobalrespository");
                    
//inserting data into JV_COMMIT table
System.out.println("Inserting in JV_COMMIT table");
JVCommit jvCommit = new JVCommit();
List<Long> jvCommitObjectList = jvCommitRepository.getMaxCommitId();
Long commitId = jvCommitObjectList.get(0) + 1;
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
jvCommit.setAuthor(req.getCheckerId());
jvCommit.setCommitDate(new Date());
jvCommit.setCommitDateInstant(date);
jvCommit.setCommitId(commitId);
System.out.println("Data inserted Successfully");
jvSnapshot.setJvCommit(jvCommit);
jvCommitRepository.save(jvCommit);   //id generated (PK)
System.out.println("JV_COMMIT Data saved Successfully");
jvSnapshot.setCommitID(jvCommit.getId());
jvSnapshotRepository.save(jvSnapshot);
                    
//inserting data into JV_SNAPSHOT table
System.out.println("Inserting in JV_SNAPSHOT table");
//CLOB Datatypes variables
                    
String existingCustomerIDNew = "somenewString";
String existingCustomerID = "someString";
jvSnapshot.setState(existingCustomerIDNew);
jvSnapshot.setChangedProperties(existingCustomerID);
                    jvSnapshot.setManagedType("com.dev.neo.models.Customer");
jvSnapshot.setType("UPDATE");
jvSnapshot.setVersion(2);
jvSnapshot.setGlobalID(jvGlobalId.getGlobalID());
System.out.println("Data inserted in all JV");
```

After all the steps, the data are not reflecting into the tables and getting an error as *`"Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.JV_SNAPSHOT_GLOBAL_ID_FK) violated - parent key not found"`*
JV_SNAPSHOT_GLOBAL_ID_FK is the foreign key constraint name of "GLOBAL_ID_FK" column of JV_SNAPSHOT table which is linked to primary key column of "GLOBAL_ID_PK" of JV_GLOBAL_ID

I have tried alternative ways of declaring one to one mapping of these tables, but none of the factors worked.

Comment: Hi, could you share the list of foreign key constraints in your database (related to this entities)

Comment: Another question : JV_SNAPSHOT contains the foreign keys to JVCommit and JVGlobal ID ?

Comment: so you can add JoinCOlumn to bith entities (JVCOmmit & JVGlobalID): @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SNAPSHOT_PK")
    private JVSnapshot jvSnapshot;

Comment: and try to insert JVCommit and JVGlobalId first after dat insert JVSnapshot

Comment: @AmineABBAOUI the constraints i used are JV_SNAPSHOT_GLOBAL_ID_FK for GLOBAL_ID_FK column of JV_SNAPSHOT and JV_SNAPSHOT_COMMIT_FK for COMMIT_FK  columns (both constraints are foreign )

Comment: Yes,JV_SNAPSHOT contains the foreign keys to JVCommit and JVGlobal ID

Comment: So I think if you make JVCommit and JVGlobalID as the owners of relation with JVSnaphot (by adding @JoinColumn(name = "SNAPSHOT_PK") to both entities JVC and JVG) you can insert them without this issue

Comment: Yes , that is very helpful but the relationship of primary and foreign key column are not limited to only one column. I have attached an image for better understanding of the relationship of tables and primary-foreign keys

Comment: By "relationship of primary and foreign key column are not limited to only one column" you mean that you have two relations, the first one with JVGlobalID and the second one is with JVCommit ?

Comment: Yes, two relations are there. But , as you can see in the image which i have attcahed, GLOBAL_ID_FK and COMMIT_FK columns of JV_SNAPSHOT table are linked to two different primary column of two different tables i.e. GLOBAL_ID_FK  is linked with GLOBAL_ID_PK  and COMMIT_FK  is linked with COMMIT_PK column

Comment: I added an example as answer

Comment: MapsId doesn't mean what you think it means - you've got too many mixes of mappings and it isn't clear why you have both references AND basic mappings for all your ID and fk columns, and as others have pointed out, it isn't clear which should be setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

In your Entity JVSnapshot you should edit your mapping like that :

> @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "GLOBAL_ID_FK") private JVGlobalID
> jvGlobalID;
>
> @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "COMMIT_FK") private JVCommit jvCommit;

And In your JVGlobalID :

> @OneToOne(mappedBy = "jvGlobalID")          private JVSnapshot
> jvSnapshot;

And in JVCommit the same thing like that :

> @OneToOne(mappedBy = "jvCommit") private JVSnapshot jvSnapshot;

Comment: After adding above piece of code , i had to add insertable=false, updatable=false to globalID and commitID of JVSnapshot class, which results in an error stating "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.dev.neo.models.JVGlobalID.jvSnapshot -> com.dev.neo.models.JVSnapshot; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance -

Comment: Why are you adding : insertable=false, updatable=false ? you should insert the JVCommit and JVGlobalID before JVSnapshot

Comment: I had inserted "insertable=false" because the piece of code which you gave me tends to give an error stating to add those parameters.

Comment: what is the error exactly ? because the idea that Hibernate can update JVSnaphot with the correct FKs